# Sorting XML with a namespace

Tags: .net, xml

Most of the examples I've found on sorting an XML query do not include a namespace. Some of them do, but I'm not finding any example of performing a query and sorting when there is a namespace.

```
 <Search xmlns="http://whatever.whatever.com/gg/whatever">
 <BinSet Type="Category">
 <Bin>
  <BinName>Clothing</BinName>
  <BinItemCount>804</BinItemCount>
   <BinParameter>
    <Name>Category</Name>
    <Value>Women's Apparel</Value>
  </BinParameter>
</Bin>
 <Bin>
  <BinName>Tools</BinName>
  <BinItemCount>126</BinItemCount>
   <BinParameter>
    <Name>Category</Name>
    <Value>Tools, handtools and hardware</Value>
  </BinParameter>
</Bin>
</BinSet>
</Search>
```

I don't have any control of the XML, so I have to deal with the namespace. Also, There are approximately 50 of these  records in the XML and it is only part of a much larger XML file.

```
Dim nsuri as string = "http://whatever.whatever.com/gg/whatever"
Dim xpath as string = "dd:Search/dd:BinSet[Type="Category"]/*"
Dim nav As XPathNavigator = doc.CreateNavigator()
Dim exp As XPathExpression = nav.Compile(xpath)
Dim nsmgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(nav.NameTable)
nsmgr.AddNamespace("dd", nsuri)
exp.SetContext(nsmgr)

exp.AddSort("BinParameter/Value", XmlSortOrder.Ascending, XmlCaseOrder.UpperFirst, "en-US", XmlDataType.Text)

' now process in sorted order
Dim iterator As XPathNodeIterator = nav.Select(exp)
While iterator.MoveNext
    Dim nav2 As XPathNavigator = iterator.Current.Clone
    nav2.MoveToFirstChild()
    Debug.WriteLine(nav2.Value) 
End While
```

All of the examples I've seen show how to sort on the immediate child nodes, for example BinName or BinItemCount in my example XML. But I need all of this information and I need to sort on the BinParameter/Value node. I've tried every way I can think of...

One last thing to note, I don't really care to use an XPathNodeIterator or XPathNavigator when all is said and done. Previously I was returning an XmlNodeList with all these records and my calling routine would traverse the nodelist to form links, like this:

```
<a href="mypage.aspx?si=Tools">Tools, handtools and hardware (126)</a>
<a href="mypage.aspx?si=Clothing">Women's Apparel (804)</a>
```

Does anyone know how to sort this XML by the nested child node "Value" using a namespace?

Also, would you know the quickest way to return the sorted results in an XmlNodeList or other .Net object so that I can have access to all of the values: BinName, BinItemCount, Name and Value? I'm not familiar with XPathNavigator or XPathNodeIterator.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `xpath` variable to

```
/dd:Sets/dd:Bin/dd:BinParameter
```

and use the following AddSort line

```
exp.AddSort("dd:Value", XmlSortOrder.Ascending, XmlCaseOrder.UpperFirst, "en-US", XmlDataType.Text)
```

(note the `dd:` prefix to all elements)

EDIT:

```
Dim iterator As XPathNodeIterator = nav.Select(exp, nsmgr)
```

Comment: I'm sorry... I didn't include my XPath declaration. It does include the prefix. It is:

Comment: Yes? (Note that your AddSort expression did not contain namespace prefixes)

Comment: Am having a difficult time figuring out how to reply... sorry. I will try your recommendation. My only concern is that I need the values of BinName and BinItemCount also. So my XPath has been /dd:Sets/dd:Bin. By setting the XPath as deep as you recommend it would seem those values will not be included? I'll try it and let you know. Thank you! Btw, my XPath did include proper prefix for the namespace.

Comment: My XPath is "dd:Sets/*". That's because I need the BinName and BinItemCount nodes also. And because I also need every <Bin>. When I include the prefix in Addsort, I get an error on this line "Dim iterator As XPathNodeIterator = nav.Select(exp)" saying "Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function."

Comment: Depending on how AddSort is implemented, it might be necessary to use a "deep" XPath, but that should be easy to test as long as the expressions work. If it is required, it should be easy to do two XPath expressions, on to retrieve the top nodes, and one to sort the Bin/Values. Ps. the Select method probably needs a reference to the namespace manager, see edited answer.